# different CSS stylesheet for iPad and iPhone in universal application

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ipad, uiwebview

I have what is essentially an offline web site embedded in a UIWebView. I've created a stylesheet to format everything nicely on the iPhone screen, but I need different formatting to take better advantage of the iPad's screen.

I tried using code to simply copy a different stylesheet into place, but this involves modifying the application bundle which is either discouraged or, in this case, just doesn't work.

Can anyone think of a way to have a different stylesheet loaded based on whether the app is running on the iPhone or iPad? I have thousands of HTML files which are synchronized with a web site so I can't very easily modify all of them. I need some way to change the stylesheet that gets loaded using javascript or by moving the css file into a certain location.

I should also mention that this is a universal application with almost the exact same code (and slightly different nib files) running on both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use a [CSS media query](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/04/using-css-media-queries-ipad.html)? You could inject it into your pages using [stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/prerelease/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString%3a).

Comment: This is the route I went with for a recent internal demo and it worked out great. Assuming that your content is mostly the same and you only want to style it differently this is certainly the quickest method I know of.

Comment: What javascript would I use to inject the CSS links though? innerHTML() or is there a better way? (Sorry, not very familiar with DOM.)

Comment: My JavaScript is crazy rusty. Perhaps @Toji can provide some guidance. I'm not sure if it's speedy or memory efficient, but you could also manipulate the HTML as a mutable string before loading it into the web view.

Comment: Why would you need javascript to inject the links? Hard code them on to your page with the correct `media` attributes and the browser will take care of the rest.

Comment: In the question, Nimrod says he can't easily modify the source files.

Answer (score 2):

Via your server side code, you could detect the [iPad User Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) and write out a `link` tag to a different stylesheet. I would probably go with server side logic rather than Javascript, simply because I don't like the possibility of a "flicker" of doing this with Javascript.

Comment: There is no server side. The UIWebView loads static content locally from the application bundle. Basically I use UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad to check whether I'm executing on an ipad then do some things differently (like present popovers for some things). I need some way to similarly modify the UIWebView to overwrite the CSS file that it loads by default.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have a look at 960 Grid System http://960.gs . It helps to use different CSS formats based on the device it encounters