# Targeting iPad via Google Ad Manager/ DFP

Tags: ipad, google-analytics, ads, google-ad-manager

I am using Google Ad Manager to publish ads on my websites, most of my ads are flash banners which wont work on ipads so I want to custom target my ads so that they wont be displayed for ipads, but how to do this in DFP ?

I found out the user agent for ipad from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) but I have no idea how to use this to target my ads.

Answer (score 2):

My answer is NOT relevant but what I have been doing for every Flash Banner Ad is, I have always added a backup gif so that the ad is still served to browser's without the Flash Plugins and also to handhelds like iPad, iPhone, BlackBerry, etc. (Android support .SWF's)

Also in DFP under the Audience tab we have a section for Computers System and if you click Edit there then you have an option for Browser and under browser's you have iPad.

Hope this helps.