# Which browser have this strange user agent? (IOS device)

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, user-agent

I recently notice that approximately 17 % of users with ios device have browser with strange user agent. This user agent like the Safari user agent but with slight modification: it does not contain `"Safari/XXXX"` string.

Example:

normal user agent of Safari:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25
```

user agent of browser that i talk:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d
```

Can somebody explain me, how it can be? Which browser have this strange user agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorter user agent comes when an ipad enters "web app" mode.  This means that a phone is parsing the html only using webkit, in full screen mode, not within a safari browser window.  Thus only the information about CPU version, webkit version, etc is sent along.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Additional discussion can be found on this very similar post:

[ipad user agent changes during use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5353926/ipad-user-agent-changes-during-use)