# Creating an iPad version of site, but show the same main URL

Tags: ipad, mobile

I have a website **http://www.domain.com** and I am creating a separate section just for the iPad.  I will be putting that in its own directory, **http://www.domain.com/ipad/** is there a way for it to pull the contents of the /ipad/ folder but only show www.domain.com?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have any example of a website doing this? Isn't a better option to serve this content from a specific mobile version, something like "m.domain.com"?

**Added:**

You can also do this. Use browser sniffing to serve a different stylesheet for the content if it is an HTTP request from an iPad. However, browser sniffing hardly works and it create good web-dev #fail joke memes. So, IMHO, using m.domain.com is the safest bet.

Answer (score 0):

aHave your website serve iPad-specific contents if incoming request has user agent string set to iPad's ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent)).

PArticular implementation of serving content based on browser user-agents depends on which webserver / application container etc. you use.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend doing this unless the content is significantly different for the iPad. This has SEO ramifications as well.

If the content is the same, a better approach is to use CSS media queries and serve a iPad styled version of the same website.