# mobylette rails gem - detect iPad

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am using successfully the mobylette rails gem:
https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette

I was wondering if anybody knows of how to disable the gem for iPads...

Thanks a bunch!

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the mobylette gem uses the code from mobile-fu (appears inactive, has [issue #21](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu/issues/21) which is your problem).

The [regex](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette/blob/master/lib/mobylette/controllers/respond_to_mobile_requests.rb#L16-20) matches the [iPad user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) on "mobile"

My suggestion -- override the is_mobile_request? controller method to:

```
#controllers/application_controller.rb
def is_mobile_request?
  return false if request.user_agent.to_s.downcase =~/ipad/
  request.user_agent.to_s.downcase =~ /#{MOBILE_USER_AGENTS}/
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs:

If you need to exclude one or more user agents from the mobile format, lets say ipad for example, you may use the :skip_user_agents option:

```
mobylette_config do |config|
  config[:skip_user_agents] = [:ipad]
end
```