# redirect to mobile site except ipad java

Tags: java, javascript, ipad, redirect, mobile

Im trying to redirect mobile devices to a mobile version, but letting Ipads view it normally. All phones redirect to the mobile site fine, but the ipad does too and i cant figure out why?...
This is the script im using.

```
<scr!pt runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] mobiles = new string[] {"midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo","novarra", 
            "palmos", "palmsource","240x320", "opwv", "chtml","pda", "windows ce", 
            "mmp/","blackberry", "mib/", "symbian","wireless", "nokia", "hand", 
            "mobi","phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", "SIE-", "SEC-", "samsung", 
            "HTC","mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony","alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx","NEC", 
            "philips", "mmm", "xx","panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch","rover", "pocket", 
            "benq", "java","pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi","bird", "compal", "kg", "voda","sany", 
            "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", "sgh", "gradi", "jb", "dddi","moto", "iphone" };
    bool isMobile = false;

    if (Request.Headers["User-Agent"] != null && Request.Browser["IsMobileDevice"] == "true")
    {
        isMobile = true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string device in mobiles)
        {
            if (Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains(device))
            {
                isMobile = true;
            }
        }
    }

    if (isMobile == true)
    {
        Response.Redirect("///SITE//");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("//SITE//");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question [What is the iPad user agent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) shows that the ipad sends the string iphone within its User-Agent string. So the final string in your array will trip it.

Maybe you could do teh reverse, i.e. if USer-Agent contains ipad redirect to normal site?

hopefully someone with more experience with ipads will be able to offer more insight.