# Web Design for iOS devices

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, design-patterns, web

I have learnt some basics about developing iOS apps and curious to learn more. I recently came across the way websites are displayed on mobile and was willing to know as to are there are particular design patterns/methods supporting it. I tried opening walmart.com on mobile which gives same display of the website as on the screen, but if I open homedepot.com; the view I get on mobile is an optimized one.

How does this work? How do I get same/optimized display for different devices i.e. desktop screen, ipad or iphone??

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways:

- use the [browser agent information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) and serve the customized files (html, css, js, etc) for that client (Generally, not recommended)
- use the [browser agent or screen-width](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/) to redirect to a mobile-specific site (what a lot of sites do; relatively easy)
- do [responsive design](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/), which essentially uses screen-widths and css to custom the display of a site, This also has a nice side effect of responding to window resizes for a desktop browser. But this method requires more work than a mobile-specific site.

Any of the methods above usually require some mobile-specific things, such as [meta tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

This tells the mobile browser to set the page width to that of the screen, and prevent zooming.

For responsive design, you can use a css framework like [320-and-up](http://stuffandnonsense.co.uk/projects/320andup/) to help. It's also a good reference to see how various mobile stuff can be done.

For a mobile-specific site, something like [jquery-mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) can help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect the type of browser that's loading your page and redirect to your mobile-optimized URL. You should probably make both the mobile-optimized and the full version of the site accessible to mobile users (see: www.progressive.com).

Google something like "iphone optimized website tutorial" to learn how.