# How to find out all versions of iPad from user-agent string?

Tags: javascript, ipad, user-agent

I wanted to find out all the version's of iPad (excluding iPhone, iPod) from user agent string, currently while testing I got the following string

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B206 Safari/7534.48.3
```

Question:
Will the following code works fine for all the iPad's?

```
String userAgentStr = request.getHeader("User-agent");
if (userAgentStr.contains("iPad"))
{
    //do my logic
}
```

EDIT:

I am using Dolphin browser from iPad but I am getting the following UA string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_2_1 like Mac OS X; en_US) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8C148 Safari/6533.18.5
```

Similarly iBrowser from iPad UA string is:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/9B206
```

So my above code is breaking...

Comment: Maybe, maybe not, maybe for now but not in the future … user agent strings are notorious for non-X to start claiming to be X because it is (to some degree) X-compatible (that user agent string doesn't come from Mozilla, OS X or Gecko, but string matching the UA would tell you it was). Don't use the UA. Use feature detection.

Comment: @Quentin How to use feature detection?

Comment: It depends on what feature you wish to detect.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+feature+detection

Comment: Why do you want to do that? There is no `contains` method for javascript string instances.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the iPad user agent?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly recommend using feature detection instead of device detection as suggested in the comments. One library commonly used for feature detection would be [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/).

If you have to use device detection, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/646272) basically says that your code should work.

Comment: Gist link is broken.