# Load a javascript file and css file depending on user agent

Tags: javascript, html, user-agent

Just like in the title.

I got two files: one is javascript file and one is css file. And if **user-agent is an iPad** I want to load those files - but only when user-agent is **iPad**. So below two lines are only loaded when user-agent is an iPad. how can i achieve that

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/c/dropkick.css" type="text/css"/>
<script src="/s/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null){ // may need changing?
  var js = document.createElement('script');
  js.type = "text/javascript";
  js.src = "/s/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js";

  var css = document.createElement('link');
  css.type = "text/css";
  css.rel = "stylesheet";
  css.href = "/c/dropkick.css";

  var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  h.appendChild(js);
  h.appendChild(css);
}
```

Or whatever would be in the `User-Agent` header for an iPad.

References:

- [`window.navigator.userAgent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.navigator.userAgent)
- [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement)
- [`node.appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.appendChild)

Comment: I always use `navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null` to detect iPad

Comment: @barts: Noted, thanks for the information. I'll update my answer to reflect.

Comment: Thank you guys for the comprehensive answer. That really helped me :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.createElement` to create `link` and `script` elements, and then append them to the document (for instance, append them to `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` or similar).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent) here on SO suggests that you can dtect an iPad by just looking for the string `"ipad"` in the `navigator.userAgent` field. Of course, the user agent field can be spoofed.

So for example:

```
<script>
(function() {
    var elm, head;

    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("ipad") !== -1) {
        head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body || document.documentElement;

        elm = document.createElement('link');
        elm.rel = "stylesheet";
        elm.href = "/c/dropkick.css";
        head.appendChild(elm);

        elm = document.createElement('script');
        elm.src = "/s/jquery.dropkick-1.0.0.js";
        head.appendChild(elm);
    }
})();
</script>
```

...but that's off-the-cuff, untested.

(Note that there's no reason to put the type on either `link` or `script`; in the case of `link`, the type comes from the content-type of the response. In the case of `script`, the default is JavaScript.)

Comment: Though I agree you don't _need_ to specify type, I get sketching from the old days of `foo.png` containing `Content-Type: text/javascript` in the header. I guess I feel like explicit is safer than implicit in a lot of cases.

Comment: @BradChristie: Right, but `type` on `link` when there's a `rel="stylesheet"` isn't explicit, it's a no-op, see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-link-element.html#attr-link-type) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#link-type-stylesheet). Similarly on `script`, the default is and **always** has been JavaScript, even on IE5 when Microsoft thought they could compete using VBScript. :-)