# making HTML and CSS "aware" of a JavaFX WebView environment

Tags: java, html, css, javafx, webview

I am working on HTML+CSS+Javascript with a Java team using the [JavaFX WebView](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html) renderer. I would also like to use the same HTML+CSS+Javascript in normal browsers, but I want a few minor differences in style, to optimize readability.

**Is there something I can ask the JavaFX programmers to do, so that my HTML+CSS+Javascript can be "aware" of the difference?** For example, a [`@media`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) query, so that I can use a different CSS in WebView vs. in normal browsers.

Comment: They could set another UserAgent, call a javascript method or you could use the -fx prefix for JavaFX only CSS. Can you be a little bit more precize about you goal? Just set another CSS file?

Comment: yeah, pretty much just set another CSS file... although I might want to use Javascript to do something different also. User-Agent is one possibility, I guess; could you elaborate on "call a javascript method" -- how can WebView do this before loading HTML?

Comment: Not before, but it can call a javascript after loading like "enableJavaFXFeatures()" or you can ask them to provide a javascript method in java FX, which you can call. But in that case, I would simply use the UserAgent.

Comment: is there a better way besides http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802639/load-a-javascript-file-and-css-file-depending-on-user-agent ?

Answer (score 1):

You can ask them to include some string in the [`userAgent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userAgentProperty) property of the `WebEngine`:

```
WebEngine engine = ...;
engine.setUserAgent(engine.getUserAgent() + " JavaFX-WebView");
```

You can check this property from javascript (`window.navigator.userAgent`), e.g.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyPage</title>
        <style>
            body {
                background-color: red;
            }
            body.javafx {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var javaFX = (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("JavaFX-WebView") > -1);
            document.body.innerHTML = javaFX ?
                    "Hello from JavaFX" : "Hello from Browser";
            if (javaFX)
                document.body.className = "javafx";
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would work for Javascript, is there a way to use it to dispatch between alternate CSS stylesheets?

Answer (score 0):

just ran across this page [Communicating between javascript and javafx](https://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/communicating_between_javascript_and_javafx) which says

> The Java application can pass arbitrary scripts to the JavaScript engine of a WebEngine object by calling the `WebEngine.executeScript()` method:
>
> ```
> webEngine.executeScript("history.back()");
> ```

So I guess I could have my Java team do something like this on initialization of each page:

```
 webEngine.executeScript("var javaFXApplicationID = 'ABCDE';");
```

and check for this in Javascript.