# How to detect whether a site is browsing from IPAD or not

Tags: php, html

I have a Web Application which is browser compatible made in php and HTML5. I have a certain requirement when a client browse the site from Ipad I want to display different banner.

```
<?php $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
   if(stripos($ua,'android') !== false) { // && stripos($ua,'mobile') !== false) {
$android = '1';

     }
     if(stripos($ua,'iPhone') !== false  || stripos($ua,'iPod') !== false  ||     strstr($ua,'iPhone') || strstr($ua,'iPod')  ) { 

$iPhone = '1';

 }

 ?>
```

This condition is working for android mobile and other devices but not for Ipad. Does anyone have idea how to detect Ipad device in php.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    if (preg_match('/ipad/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'iPad';
    }
```

here is what i use for rest of them:

```
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/ubuntu/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Ubuntu';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Windows';
    }

    if (preg_match('/android/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Android';
    }

    if (preg_match('/palm/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Palm';
    }


    if (preg_match('/iphone/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'iPhone';
    }

    if (preg_match('/blackberry/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'Blackberry';
    }

    if (preg_match('/ipod/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'iPod';
    }

    if (preg_match('/ipad/i', $ua)) 
    {
        $platform = 'iPad';
    }
```

Comment: Not sure OP needs a regular expression for this.  I think `stripos` would work fine.

Comment: I rely on regex more than strpos :D

Comment: Why don't you use something like `$regex = '/android|blackberry|iphone/i';` then `preg_match($regex, $ua, $platform);`  Then $platform[0] should equal the platform, or be empty.

Comment: does not work with i phone 6 - I know this is like 2 years old but does  any one have an updated pregmatch

Answer (score 2):

I believe the user agent has 'ipad' in it.  Search for ipad.

If you're curious, use a page to spit out the HTTP USER AGENT, and visit with an ipad:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
?>
```