# Conditional include on css file for ipad

Tags: javascript, css

I need to stop inclusion of a specific CSS file only after checking if its an ipad or not

Can this be done using javascript or css

something like

```
<!--[if !isAppleProduct()]>
   <link href="./css/fluid.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: You can't test to see if it's an apple product but you can use media queries to change your CSS depending on the screen resolution.

Comment: Try looking into getting its user-agent. I don't think it's very accurate, but atleast it's something. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2153877/what-is-the-ipad-user-agent

Comment: Actually mitchell, it won't work in my case, so i m just trying to find out an option like <!--[if IE 9]>, this syntax tells if the browser in IE 9 so is there an syntax which tells if the client is an ipad ?

Comment: What language are you looking to use JS or PHP? It can't be done with on conditional statement you will either need to use JS or PHP to detect the users browser and or OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **conditional comment** syntax you're using is a IE-only feature (discontinued in IE10) so you can't use that to detect anything else.

With JavaScript however, you can do something like the following;

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") > -1) {
    // add classname "iPad" to the <body>
    document.body.classList.add("iPad");
}
```

Then you can prefix any CSS rules with `.iPad` to only apply to the iPad.

```css
.iPad .myClass {
    /* iPad-specific css */
}
```

---

Alternatively, you could use the same test to include an ipad-specific css file:

```js
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") > -1) {
    var ipadCss = document.createElement("link");
    ipadCss.type = "text/css";
    ipadCss.rel = "stylesheet";
    ipadCss.href = "/path/to/ipad.css";
    document.head.appendChild(ipadCss);
}
```

Comment: Thanks xec, the last option worked "document.head.appendChild(ipadCss)"

Answer (score 0):

```
@media only screen and (not (min-device-width : 768px)) and (not (max-device-width : 1024px)),
only screen and (not (min-device-width : 320px)) and (not (max-device-width : 568px)),
only screen and (not (min-device-width : 320px)) and (not (max-device-width : 480px)){
    /* CSS for Apple product here */
}
```

First row enable CSS for iPads, second row - for iPhone5 and third row - for iPhone4 or early

Comment: He said he doesn't want to use media queries and PS that doesn't detect is it's an Apple product that just test the screen's resolution.

Comment: Hmmmm... Its an entire css file that i need to skip being included for ipad, irrespective on screen width

Comment: I change my answer with "not" operator

Answer (score 0):

Put this into header.php

```
<?php 
    $iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
    $iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
    $iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
    if( $iPod || $iPhone || $iPad){ ?>
        <style type="text/css">
           /* put your css code */
    }
        </style>
    <?php }
?>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [headjs](http://headjs.com/). You can detect the type of platform / device by using identifying the `userAgent` and then loading the css conditionally based on this.